# How can I format HTML in a JSP file using PHPStorm?

Tags: jsp, code-formatting, phpstorm

I am using **PHPStorm 4.0.3** and I'm working a project that includes JSP files. Changing the ide is not an option. I would like PHPStorm to **treat JSP files as HTML** when it comes to code formatting.

To format the HTML code I select the entire contents and click on the **Menu item "Code" --> "Reformat Code"**. This works in html files but not in JSP.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: PhpStorm doesn't support JSP code formatting. To treat JSP files as HTML you can change the mappings in `Settings` | `File Types`. For complete JSP+PHP support consider IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Thanks, that worked! I added the pattern *.jsp to the HTML file type under "File Types". Please post your comment as an answer, so I can mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To treat JSP files as HTML you can change the mappings in `File` | `Settings` | **File Types**, add `*.jsp` to `HTML Files`.

Comment: However, there's a big problem with that: you lose any JSP "aspect" of the page. No code completions, no syntax hightlighting and no formatting of the Java code inside the JSP.

Comment: I tried looking for this setting and couldn't find it.  Do you know where it can be found in PHPStorm 8?  I did not see a Settings menu under File anywhere so looked all throughout the Preferences section under the PHPStorm menu.. couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the Plugins options page in PHPStorm Preferences, there is a plugin named Java Server Pages Integration which adds some support for JSP.

It adds a JSP page under the Code Style node of the Settings/Preferences dialog.

---

I recently started working on a project which utilizes JSP templates and found that when I needed to copy and paste code, PHPStorm would screw up the formatting and paste everything in with each line of code positioned 1 tab from the left.

The best solution I found to maintain the existing formatting when copy/pasting is to use the <kbd>Paste Simple</kbd> option.  Using this option results in the code being pasted in with the same formatting that it had when copying it.

[image]

> [PHPStorm 8.0.2 Cutting, Copying, and Pasting](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/cutting-copying-and-pasting.html)
>   The `Paste Simple` command helps paste any Clipboard entry as a plain text, without any analysis.

Answer (score -1):

You can find the `file types` here:

[image]